# Databases supporting intersection of multipolygons and a set of points

Tags: postgis, spatial-database

Currently we use PostGIS to store thousands of MULTIPOLYGONs and we can then use ST_Intersects to return any that rows contain any point in an input collection of points. Are there any other open source databases that can support this type of functionality, or is this unique to PostGIS?

**EDIT:** WE need to have proper intersects functionality, not just MBR, all our geometries will be in 4326, and we are interested in solutions for mobile devices, going forward.

Comment: Is ST_Intersects the only function you will be running? And when you say input collection of points, do you mean in a table, as a single MultiPoint, or something else. You can do basic intersections with MySQL, spatiallite, MongoDB, CouchDB (and others), but they all have limitations/differences of one form or another compared to the Postgres/Postgis combination. But, I think you need to clarify your set up a bit more, for anyone to be able to clearly answer this.

Comment: The collection of points comes from ST_Collect on another table to the one I call ST_Intersect on. I'm looking for an accurate ST_Intersects and not rectangular bounding or anything like that. To clarify:
- I have complex multipolygons in one table
- I have a collection of points harvested from a second table
- I need an accurate result for knowing which of the multipolygons contains any of the points
I'm very happy with PostgreSQL/PostGIS but just wondering if I am 100% tied to it or will have options later, especially in the NoSQL area like CouchDB.

Comment: Are you interested in converting from one coordinate system to another? Are you just using lat/lon or some other SRID. What appeals to you about CouchDB, flexible schema, partition tolerance, something else? Sorry for all the questions, but they are such different beasts, it is hard to give a useful answer without narrowing it down somewhat.

Comment: Sorry also for my vagueness. I am just beginning in GIS. We're only using 4326 coordinate system. I start with lat/lon and convert them to geom points in PostGIS. CouchDB is being used for its offline replication capabilities, particularly for mobile. So we statically export as much JSON as we can (including lat/lon points) from Postgres to CouchDB so that it can be replicated to mobile clients. Hence I'm also interested in any solution which would let me check intersections of multipolygons and points on mobile too.

Comment: No worries. I will attempt to answer later, bit busy right now, unless someone beats me to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geocouch (which provides R-tree indexing for CouchDB) and CouchDB only support bounding box intersections at this time, though I know that more extended functionality has been in the pipeline for some time. So, if you need a proper intersects function, you will have to write your own Map-reduce function on the results of a bounding box query, which is probably less than ideal. CouchDB has many strengths, such as being mobile ready and having extreme partition failure tolerance.

MongoDB does allow intersects via the [$geoIntersects](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/geoIntersects/) function and you can also get results ranked in order with [geonear](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/geoNear/) or use the aggregation version for further attribute processing, after a geo filter has been applied. Spatial indexing in Mongo is based on geohashing, which reduces two dimensions to one, so that it can be indexed with a B-tree. This can lead to worse query times than an R-tree index, such as used by Postgres/Postgis. Further, MongoDB **does not have a mobile** version, which you have expressed an interest in.

Of the NoSQL offeringd, Neo4J is worth mentioning as it does have a bit more spatial functionality than Couch or Mongo, but it is such a different beast, being based around graph search, that it probably doesn't meet your needs at all.

Postgres/Postgis is by far the most fully functional, from a spatial perspective, handling not just hundreds of vector functions, but raster and topology too. However, it is in a different part of the [Cap Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem) triangle than the other two -- being fully ACID compliant, and therefore favoring consistency, over partition tolerance and availability, which may or may not be what you are looking for. Having said that, a properly configured Postgres cluster, can handle serious load, and it is a bit of a myth that you can't scale traditional RDBMS.

If you are attracted to the schema-less nature of NoSQL, you might be interested in a feature of Postgres coming out in 9.4, namely [JSONB](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html), which is a proper binary JSON type, but with good indexing on top (unlike Hstore, which always felt a bit bolted on to me). Postgres is not mobile ready, of course, but lots of people combine an RDBMS with something else these days, if the use case really demands it.