# What options are there for geolocation-aware SQL databses?

Tags: postgresql, sql, software-recommendations, mysql, mariadb

I need to implement an SQL database that can make queries using geo-location  based logic.

e.g.
select rows within 500m of coordinate x, y

What options are available to do this with sqlite, mySQL, postgreSQL, mariaDB, or something similar?

Comment: There is a question on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743632/gis-postgis-postgresql-vs-mysql-vs-sql-server/22576304#22576304) that deals with this -- note shameless plug for my own (very) long answer there :D If you feel a bit of TL;DR there, I recommend Postgis in the end -- Postgres is amazingly fully featured and stable and Postgis has far more functions than MySQL/Maria, MongoDB, CouchDB. Sqlite is OK for smaller projects too as HeyOverThere has said.

Comment: And, of course, SQL-Server, Oracle, DB2 and Informix all support spatial types as well, as do several NoSQL databases.

Comment: @Vince. Yes, I also wrote a post about [NoSQL options](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115248/databases-supporting-intersection-of-multipolygons-and-a-set-of-points/115529#115529), but the available functions are still some way away from Postgis, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.

Answer (score 1):

All four of the databases you listed have the capability to support the type of query you're asking about.  SQLite and Postgres through extensions (Spatialite & PostGIS respectively), mySQL and MariaDB have some basic GIS support built in natively.

As to which to use, it depends on your needs.  Personally I go with SQLite for simple in house applications and Postgresql for bigger projects that are going to get more traffic.